# How to attach a date stamp with Angularjs (easy mode)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have done an example of how to display date in a page. I have made a js called dateFilter.js . How do I connect it to the html page? (I have the ng-view in my index page)

This is the dateFilter.js

```
(function()
{
    angular
        .module('myWeb')
            .filter('date', function ($filter) {
                return function (input) {
                    if (input == null) {
                        return "";

                    }

                    var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMM dd yyyy');

                    return _date.toUpperCase();
                };
            });
    })();
```

I have connected the js to the index page and the development tool (fire Bug) show that I've connected.

This is how I tried to connect (home.html)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>HELLO!</h2>
        <div ng-bind="date in dates">
            {{date.date1}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i do this it says that i have an error in the word "in" also. 
Can someone help to overcome his problem?

Probably I haven't connected it properly. Can someone help me with the problem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally did it in a simple way. I should've use a controller like this. Thanks for the help guys! :)

dateController.js

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('myWeb')
        .controller('dateController', dateController);
    dateController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function dateController($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.today = new Date();
    }
})();
```

Then whatever the page you want to have the date:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>HELLO!</h3>

        <div ng-controller="dateController">
            {{today | date: 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to attach the js using `<script>` tag. There you have it!

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner you should read the reference and do some tutorials to learn the language.

On first sight I can see 3 problems:

1. You defined a date filter but you don't use it in the HTML code.
2. Your date filter is calling itself and will cause an infinite loop.
3. Did you define a `dates` array to use in your `ng-repeat` loop?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to write out all dates, but instead of using ng-repeat, you are using ng-bind.

Try to do this instead

```
<div ng-repeat="date in dates">
```

I cannot see from your html, whether you have a ng-app somewhere, but if not, you will need that as well. Something like this:

```
ng-app="myWeb"
```

Comment: Yes i have an app.js the thing is i don't want to repeat i just want to display a date in my page. How to accomplish this. In the example it shows many dates. When I tried this anyway it didn't work. actually the whole div tag doesn't show up.